# Sharepointplus: need tips to get started

Tags: sharepointplus

I saw references to the SharePointPlus library and am keen to try it out.
Unfortunately i have not been able to make this work.
The script below is in the HTML source of my webpart. Would appreciate your inputs.

i do not see the alert not the console log. i am not sure if there is any configuration missing

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sharepointplus@5.0.0/sharepointplus-5.0.min.js">
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/promise-polyfill@7/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
   console.log("Test");
   $SP().list("APP Projects").get({fields:"ID"}, function(data) {
   alert("Number of items: "+data.length)
   })

   },"sp.js");
   });
   </script>
```

Comment: What is exactly not working...?

Comment: Hello. i do not see the alert not the console log. i am not sure if there is any configuration missing

Answer (score 0):

Old message, but here some tips...

You don't need to put SharepointPlus code inside `$(document).ready` or `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`. It can work right away.

Then, the `"APP Projects"` must be the correct name of a list in the current website where the code is displayed.

Finally, you can use Promise:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$SP().list("APP Projects").get({fields:"ID"})
.then(function(data) {
  alert("Number of items: "+data.length)
})
</script>
```